# How should this test be understood, and should it be written differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a piece of code where the length of `v` is either 0, 1 or 2, and can contain identical or different data and data types.

```
result = False
v = [3, 4]  # just an example, could be v = [None, None] instead
try:
    result |= v[0] == v[1] is not None  # THIS IS THE TEST
except Exception:
    pass
```

How should the line `result |= v[0] == v[1] is not None` be understood? Should it be written in another way (whatever it is supposed to be doing)?

Comment: What is the logic the test is _supposed_ to be expressing? `v[0] == v[1] is not None` is [comparison-chained](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) to `v[0] == v[1] and v[1] is not None`, so it's true if both values are equal but _not_ both `None`.

Comment: For what I have tested, it is comparing the two values in `v` and returns `True` if they are equal unless the second value is `None`, where in that case it seems to be returning `False` (and the `OR` and creates an `exception` if there is less than one value in `v`). However I have no idea how it is actually executed by Python and whether it does what I think this test does. Is there a way of knowing how actually Python interprets this test?

Answer (score 4):

First, to know what this test is doing, you need to know what `|=` means.
|=, is the same sort of shortcut as +=, this means that

```
a |= b
```

actually means

```
a = a | b
```

A common case for the operator `|` is for dictionnaries :

```
dict1 = {"a":10, "b":12}
dict2 = {"c":80, "d":37}
dict3 = dict1 | dict2
print(dict3)
```

Result :

```
{"a":10, "b":12, "c":80, "d":37}
```

This is a sort of "merge" operator, it merges an union with another union, or data with another data, to be simple.

Now that this is understood, we need to focus on the other part of the test :

```
v[0] == v[1] is not None
```

This test simply means

> Does the condition `v[0] == v[1]` equals `not None`?
> If it does equals to `not None`, returns `True`

In this case: `v[0] = 3` and `v[1] = 4`

So, this condition is :

```
(3 == 4) is (not None)
False is (not None)
```

False isn't `not None`
So, this test returns False.

Now, the full test : `result |= v[0] == v[1] is not None`

What does it do ? It symply do :

> Merge the variable `result` equals to the returned value of the test `v[0] == v[1] is not None`

As we know, this : `v[0] == v[1] is not None` returns False, so it simply says :

> Merge the variable `result` with the returned value of `v[0] == v[1] is not None`

So :

> Merge the variable `result` with `False`

False merged with False makes False. So,all of this simply makes the result variable being `False`.

This is why, when printing `result`, it prints `False` !
(Hope that helps)